# Make an android app for adding words to user dictionary

Tags: android, dictionary

I am trying to make an app for adding a custom txt file to android user dictionary. I am extremely new to android programming and this is the first app I'm trying to make. I would like to have a simple screen with a single button, which when pressed, just adds the words in text file to the users dictionary. At the moment, the user does not have the ability to choose which text file. Its a simple one click operation for my target user base. Android has this API to add words to user dictionary, but I have no clue how to use it :-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.Words.html

This is as far as I've gotten till now, I've just created a button and don't know how to give it that function. Any help will be greatly appreciated :) Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.spandanmadan1.hinglish;

import android.provider.UserDictionary;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Button bsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        bsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                UserDictionary.Words.addWord(getApplicationContext(),"hoogakabooga",1,"hoog",null);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you publish your app so we can use it?

Comment: IT's on android play store by the name Hinglish

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that? I see HINGLISH app by TypeLabs and in its thescription I don't see mentioned option for importing custom TXT file into Android dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Initialise your button in the onCreate method like:

```
Button bSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton); //This should be the id of the concerned submit button in your xml
```

Then just add a click listener to it, which basically performs some operation when the button is clicked.

```
bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    //Do something on button click -- Add words to dictionary
    UserDictionary.Words.addWord(getActivity(), "Word", 1, "", Locale.ENGLISH)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply, and I'm sorry to be asking such silly questions. But, Where am I to put the above code? I'm using Android Studio as my IDE, I created a new project with a blank activity, that has an XML file (text and design tabs) and I have the .java file.

Comment: You can put this in the onCreate method of your .java class (Activity). I suggest you go through some sort of tutorial to help you get started, before diving into a whole app :).  [This](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) is a good introduction by Google

Comment: Hi, I figured that much out! Sorry for such a silly question. Its compiling fine but app crashes when I click the button!

Comment: Can you paste the error log (logcat) as well as your layout .xml file?

Comment: Made it work :) The app needed some permissions, went into the manifests and gave it the requisite permissions :) Thanks a ton for all your help :D

Comment: This isn't quite right.  The last argument to addWord() is a Locale object, not a String.

Comment: @peastman You're right, thanks for pointing that out. Edited my answer.